# Using java stream on HTTP Headers

Tags: http, header, http-headers, java-stream, httpresponse

Just for practice purposes, I want to use Java 8's **stream** functionality to implement code, where I am looking for a **HTTP header** name and returning the value associated with it.

For example, just say activeResponse is my HttpResponse that is rendered from a url.

Instead of doing:
[Iterating through headers with a for-loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BenFz.png)

I want to implement this code using a stream. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  String result = Arrays.stream(headers)
                  .filter(h -> h.getName().equals("Content-Type"))
                 .findFirst()
                 .map(Header::getValue)
                 .orElse("NotFound");
```